# Firebase & Android Studio, unable to get past: W/SyncTree: Listen at /message failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Steps to replicate what I do:

**Step 1)** New Project example name: com.myapp.test

**Step 2)** New android app on firebase console, name: com.myapp.test (just as in the manifest)

**Step 3)** Download google-services.json and place it on the 'app' folder of my project

**Step 4)** Add the following lines:

**Build.gradle** - *Project Level*

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

**Build.gradle** - *App level* (at the bottom of the file)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also take the opportunity to add a couple of dependencies from Firebase I'm going to use, such as:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

**Step 5)** Main Activity (on create)

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

**Step 6)** Run it and get the following:

```
W/SyncTree: Listen at /message failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
W/MainActivity: Failed to read value.
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
     at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source)
     at com.myapp.test.MainActivity$1.onCancelled(MainActivity.java:50)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajp.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakn.zzcxi(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run(Unknown Source)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I've tried starting from scratch at least 5 times, different names and all. Even adding fingerprint. However, no matter what I do, I can't shake this error.

I can make it work by going to the 'Permissions' tab on the console and change 'auth != null' to true. But that's a bandaid, I need a permanent solution.

My hands are sort of tied here, ran out of things to try. I do get the following messages that may or may not have something to do with the error above:

```
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.myapp.test, real application class is null.
```

And also:

```
W/DynamiteLoaderImpl: Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.flags not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only permanent solution is to sign in the user of the app with Firebase Authentication.

The simplest way to do that is to [sign in with anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously) and only writing to the database when that succeeds:

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously()
     .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
           FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
           DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
           myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
         }
       }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks I see no other way. Works fine on Javascript in a web browser without having to do that, that's the reason for my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Either authenticate prior to writing to the DB or change your security rules to allow non authenticated users to read/write.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/